# Package for writing definitions in LaTeX

Tags: beamer, packages

I want to write a definition in LaTeX.Is there a package or class that takes the definition , the author as arguments and prints in a standard definition format.In Google , they give package only for theorems which I don't require now.[image]

Comment: What is 'standard definition format'?

Comment: What have you already tried? Can you provide a sample of the output you would like to get?

Comment: This is tagged as beamer. If so, beamer provides an environment for formatting definitions, explained on page 119 of the user manual. So you can write \begin{definition}[term]Explanation of term\end{definition}.

Comment: Voted to close as there was never any feedback and quite honestly, i don't understand the question. You can improve the question and ask for reopening.